# Tensorflow installation: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install Tensorflow on my computer. The python version is 3.6.5 64x and I believe all the prerequisites are satisfied. Below is the error I get. Do you know how to solve this problem?

```
 Building wheels for collected packages: absl-py
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for absl-py ... error
  Failed building wheel for absl-py
  Running setup.py clean for absl-py
Failed to build absl-py
Installing collected packages: absl-py, tensorflow
  Running setup.py install for absl-py ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 24: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 24: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing tensorflow with Pip?

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

or

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

If this doesn't work, maybe try uninstalling then reinstalling tensorflow.

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
```

Comment: but not gpu mode since my computer does not have the gpu i'll try to reinstall it

Comment: ok, the system cannot uninstall the tensorflow because it wasn't installed at the first time.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this or try to get the different tfBinaryURL from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package

```
pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.7.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```